# Will IMAP using C# AE.Net.Mail work after desupport of basic authentication

Tags: imap, exchange-basicauth

Microsoft has announced [end of life support for basic authentication for office 365](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/) - the 13th October 2020.

Will the [AE.Net.Mail libaray](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail) (currently version 1.7.10.0) still be usable to connect after this date using

`var client = new ImapClient(host, username, password, AuthMethods.Login, port, true);`

Comment: You can easily find out; enable debugging so you get a log of the IMAP commands sent, and see whether your connections use a command such as AUTHENTICATE PLAIN or LOGIN.

Answer (score 2):

No, AE.Net.Mail will not work anymore for Office365 once Microsoft ends support for basic authentication.

You'll need an IMAP library that supports the XOAUTH2 SASL mechanism.

Update: I've had several people ask me how to obtain the proper OAuth2 access-token credentials via Microsoft Graph for use with [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), so I've reached out to the Office365 development team in order to try and get that information. Once I've got that info, I'll write up a HOWTO document and include it with MailKit.

Comment: did you ever write this up? Thanks!